# DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChange not fire

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, webforms, autopostback

I have two dropdownlists, two both with AutoPostBack="true". 
The first dropdowlist have a list of customers and the second have a list of employees.

A screenshot:

[image: My Program]

When I select a item on first dropdown (on fildset 1 "Dados") the fildset 2 "Cliente" must fill the white spaces (like name, zipcode, adress, phone number, etc).

BUT NOTHING HAPPEN! 
There are OnSelectedIndexChange event and AutoPostBack="true" but nothing works.
But when I change the second dropdownlist "Tecnico" the first dropdownlist fire!

This is my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGeral" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div >
                <h1>Relatório de Atendimento</h1>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <fieldset style="width: 90%">
                        <legend>Dados</legend>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label Text="Cliente" runat="server" ID="lblCliente"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClientes" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClientes_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblIdCliente" runat="server" Height="23px"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
                                        <ProgressTemplate>
                                            <img src="../Imagens/Icones/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
                                        </ProgressTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Responsável" ID="lblResponsavel"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtResponsavel"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Data Chegada" ID="lblDataChegada"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDataChegada" onkeyup="formataData(event);" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td class="style3">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Hora Chegada" onkeyup="formataHora(event);" MaxLength="5"
                                        ID="lblHoraChegada"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="style4">
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHoraChegada" onkeyup="formataHora(event);" MaxLength="5"
                                        Style="margin-left: 0px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Data Saída" ID="lblDataSaida"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDataSaida" onkeyup="formataData(event);" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td class="style3">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Hora Saída" ID="lblHoraSaida"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="style4">
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHoraSaida" onkeyup="formataHora(event);" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblKM" runat="server" Text="KM"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtKM" runat="server" onkeyup="formataInteiro(event);"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTecnico" runat="server" Text="Técnico"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTecnico" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
</ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlClientes" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I don't know what I can do to fix it...
Somebody can help me?

Comment: The most strange is if I comment the second Dropdownlist the first fire!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set "UpdateMode" updatePanel property as "Conditional".